# How to extend ListActivity class and Fragment class with my Mainclass?

Tags: java, android, listactivity

I am new to android and in desperate need of help.
I have successfully created a ListView with images.My task is when I click on any list item its description should appear on the right hand side of the ListView in tablet. No doubt this can be accomplished with the help of fragments. But to use fragments the Main class should extend Fragment class , But my Problem is that my class is already extending ListActivity class.what should I do now?

I have three java files in my Project:
        MainActivity.java [This should be the first fragment],
        CustomArrayAdapter.java and
        Fragment2.java [This should be the second fragment]

Here s the code

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.mypractice;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle; 
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
String[] menu = {
"Internet",
"Movies",
"Songs",
"Games",
"News",
"Menu",
"Bill",
"Call Waiter"
 };
Integer[] imageIDs = {
R.drawable.pancake,
};
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
CustomArrayAdapter adapter = new
CustomArrayAdapter(this, menu, imageIDs);
setListAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

**CustomArrayAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.mypractice;
import android.app.Activity;    
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Activity context;
private final String[] menu;
private final Integer[] imageIds;
public CustomArrayAdapter(Activity context,
String[] presidents, Integer[] imageIds) {
super(context, R.layout.lvrowlayout2, presidents);
this.context = context;
this.menu = presidents;
this.imageIds = imageIds;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
Log.d("CustomArrayAdapter",String.valueOf(position));
LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.lvrowlayout2, null, true);
TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtPresidentName);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
txtTitle.setText(menu[position]);
imageView.setImageResource(imageIds[position]);
return rowView;
}
}
```

**Fragment2.java**

```
package com.example.mypractice;
import android.app.ListActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
public class Fragment2 extends ListActivity {
String[] menu = {
"PanCakes with Butter and Honey",
"PanCakes with Butter and Honey",
};
Integer[] imageIDs = {
R.drawable.pancake,
R.drawable.pancake,
};
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.fragment2);

this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
this,
R.layout.lvrowlayout,
R.id.txtPresidentName,
presidents));
CustomArrayAdapter adapter = new
CustomArrayAdapter(this, menu, imageIDs);
setListAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An activity is not a fragment. Your activity needs to *contain* fragments. Consider having a main activity that contains a listview fragment and an image display fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Try extending the class as ListFragment

Answer (score 0):

You are basically wondering how to [Build a Dynamic UI with Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html) or how to [Design for Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html).

Your ListActivity should become a ListFragment inside a FragmentActivity plus all the logic to switch between the two kind of layouts.